# How to return a similar Python list of tuple of list and string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am writing a program in JavaScript , that will traverse a nested `JSON schema` and I want it to return a list of tuple of `Paths` and `Values` for a given `schema key`

This is my sample data

```
var data = {"a":"hello",
            "b":{"a":"world"},
            "c":[{"a":"Good"},{"d":"Morning"}]}
```

And I want my program to return for given key `a`

```
 [(['a'],'hello'),(['b','a'],'world'),(['c',0,'a'],'Good')]
```

Below is my script , currently it returns `values` of `key 'a'` `[ 'hello', 'world', 'Good' ]`.And I am able to console the `Paths` too , but unable to return both `Paths` and `values` in above mentioned format.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

function _generate_values(data, key,path){
    if (Array.isArray(data)) { 
        return _.map(data,function(x, idx){
            return _generate_values(x, key,path.concat([idx]))
          }
        )
    }else if(typeof data==="object"){
        return _.map(
            _.keys(data),
            function(x){ 
                if(x===key){
                    console.log(path.concat(x)) // consoles paths ['a'],['b','a'],['c',0,'a']
                    return _.get(data,x) // returns [ 'hello', 'world', 'Good' ]
                }else{
                    return _generate_values(_.get(data, x), key,path.concat([x]))
                }
                
            }
        )
    }else{
        return null
    }
}

    
function find_values_(data, key, paths =false)
    {    
       return( _.chain(_generate_values(data, key,[]))
            .flattenDeep()
            .compact()
            .value()
       )
    }
  
console.log(find_values_(data,'a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript don't have tuples, but you can return a 2-element array.

`return [path, _.get(data,x)]`